# Annotation in MKMapView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I want an animated image as annotation in my Mapview in iOS. I tried one gif image with the help of a third party library to animate, but it won't animate but it animate in normal imageview. I also tried animatedImageNamed with the help of 3 images, but it won't work. How can add animation in my annotation. I want a dot with animated layers (layers are appear and disappear). Just like attached image

[image]

Comment: You said "but it won't work", it is crashed?

Comment: No.. When i used animatedImageNamed, it shows only first image. Won't animate.. I edited the question to avoid confusion

Comment: You can always create a custom annotationView, add your imageView and your custom animation